# Why doesn't Chrome decode location.hash and print decoded characters？

Tags: google-chrome, url, web

Type the following url address in Chrome location bar:

"www.αααααα.com/αααααα/αααααα.html#αααααα"

Then enter, it turned out to be:

"www.αααααα.com/αααααα/αααααα.html#%CE%B1%CE%B1%CE%B1%CE%B1%CE%B1%CE%B1"

In IE, there's no such problem, so is it a bug for Chrome?

I want to know how to make Chrome display decoded characters after "#".

Currently I have a single page app whose history relies on location.hash, and if that the hash can be pretty printed in the location bar will be great for users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed in Chrome 65 https://crbug.com/789163, which is stable soon.

It seems to me that this was inadvertently changed while making sure other characters like `` <>"` `` were escaped https://crbug.com/810798.

See [291](https://github.com/whatwg/url/issues/291), [344](https://github.com/whatwg/url/issues/344), and [347](https://github.com/whatwg/url/pull/347) in [whatwg/url](https://github.com/whatwg/url).